# Apache2 Custom header - Adding Remort Port on header

Tags: http, header, apache2

I try to add a custom header on my request, but I'm not sure if it's possible with Apache2.4.

I would like to add to my headers the remote port used by the client.
If I check my logformat, I can get the remote port with this syntax :
`%{remote}p`

But if I try something like :

`Header add x-remote-port %{remote}p`

My configtest give me this error :
`Unrecognized header format %p`

I would like to know if it's possible to get a dynamic variable like remote port to add it on my headers for each requests ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Log format syntax are differents, so here we go for the header module syntax :

`Header add X-remote-port "%{REMOTE_PORT}e"`

REMOTE_PORT varirable works only on `2.4.26` and later

https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/expr.html